# Explain me like I'm 5 - ES6 Promises & async/await differences and is my code "right"?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm having difficulties understanding ES6 Promises and Async/await.

I looked up for videos on youtube explaining those topics and still my head cannot sink inm what is the difference between them and when should I use Promises over Async/await or Async/await over Promises?

Also when do I know if my code is "valid" promises or async/await.

Here I have two examples (both working) that fetches "companies" from my local JSON server and when it's finished, it loops through those companies.

First example: ( Using Promises )

```
function getCompanies() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/companies`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => resolve(response))
        .catch(error => reject(error))
    })
}

function loopCompanies(companies) {
    companies.forEach((company) => {
        console.log(company);
    })
}

getCompanies().then(response => loopCompanies(response)).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Second Example: (Using Async/await)

```
async function getCompanies() {
    let response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/companies`);

    let processedResponse = await response.json();

    return processedResponse
}

function loopCompanies(companies) {
    companies.forEach((company) => {
        console.log(company);
    })
}

async function doIt() {
    try{
        let response = await getCompanies();
        loopCompanies(response)
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
doIt()
```

So I wan't know if that's how I should use Promises in Example 1?

Is that how I should use Async/await in Example 2 ?

And what are the differences between them

Comment: The first example is unnecessarily wrapping your result in a manually created promise.  No need to do that at all and that is an anti-pattern.  You can just do `return fetch(...).then(...);`.

Comment: `async/await` is syntactic sugar over promises. It's only there to provide alternative syntax that might be nicer in some cases or preferable to some people. Promises and `async/await` are just alternatives to one another.

Comment: @jfriend00 Just like that?
```
function getCompanies() {
    return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/companies`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => loopCompanies(response))
            .catch(error => reject(error))
}

function loopCompanies(companies) {
    companies.forEach((company) => {
        console.log(company);
    })
}
``` 
and what about example 2?

Comment: @VLAZ that answers one of my questions, thank you

Comment: No, not like that.  See the code in the answer I posted.

Comment: To get you on the right track, Promises and Async/await are not competing concepts. It's neither about "Promises over Async/await" nor "Async/await over Promises". 
(1) A Promise is an object that represents an asynchronous value. 
(2) There are two alternative syntaxes for accessing the value delivered by a Promise (a) via the Promise's `.then()` method, (b) by using language keyword `await`.
(3) The two syntaxes may be mixed but it is generally recommended not to do so; within any particular function use one syntax or the other; a calling function may differ from the function(s) it calls.

Comment: (4) `await` is only available in an `async Function`
(5) An `async Function` is guaranteed to return Promise.
(6) If an `async Function` throws, then the Error will be reflected in the settlement of the returned Promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example is unnecessarily wrapping a manually created promise around a promise you already have.  This is an anti-pattern for a variety of reasons.  You should just return the promise that `fetch()` already returns.  You can do this:

```
function getCompanies() {
    return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/companies`)
        .then(response => response.json());
    })
}

function loopCompanies(companies) {
    companies.forEach((company) => {
        console.log(company);
    })
}

getCompanies().then(response => loopCompanies(response)).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

---

The second example (using `async/await`) looks fine to me.  You can simplify it a bit by changing this:

```
async function getCompanies() {
    let response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/companies`);
    let processedResponse = await response.json();
    return processedResponse
}
```

to this:

```
async function getCompanies() {
    let response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/companies`);
    return response.json();
}
```

As there is no need to `await` a value you are just going to `return`.  Instead, you can just return the promise directly.  Either generates the same result, but the second way does it with less code.

---

> I looked up for videos on youtube explaining those topics and still my head cannot sink inm what is the difference between them and when should I use Promises over Async/await or Async/await over Promises?

`async` and `await` absolutely use promises.  In fact, `await` does nothing useful unless you `await` a promise.  And, `async` functions ALWAYS return a promise.  So, `async/await` are not an alternative to promises.  They are an alternative to `.then()` that gives you a  different syntax that is sometimes more friendly to write, debug and read, particularly when you want to sequence multiple asynchronous operations.

> Also when do I know if my code is "valid" promises or async/await.

Your code is valid when it delivers the proper result in both success and error conditions and is written without unnecessary steps and without anti-patterns.  There's no magic answer beyond that.  There is no tool I'm aware of that will tell you that.  Just like there's no tool that will tell you if you're 100 line function is written well or not.  You have to learn good coding practices for Javascript asynchronous development and then you will recognize good patterns and not-so-good patterns.

> So I wan't know if that's how I should use Promises in Example 1?

See my fixed up example above for removing the anti-pattern from Example 1.

> Is that how I should use Async/await in Example 2 ?

Yes, that's fine, but it can be simplified further as I showed in my example above.

> And what are the differences between them

In my two amended examples, they accomplish the same result.  They are just two different coding styles.  You can decide which one you prefer.  Neither is "more right" than the other.

My personal style is to use `async/await` when there's a good reason to use it such as:

1. Multiple asynchronous operations I'm sequencing.
2. When it leads to simpler, foolproof error handling.
3. When it leads to simpler looking code.
4. When I want to make sure synchronous exceptions get caught and turned into a rejected promise.
5. When I don't need to run in older JS engines that might not support `async/await` without transpiling.

Comment: @JustinasDev - I added more specific answers to your questions.